# парсинг текстовика и вывод нужной строки

Tags: python

помогите пожалуйста, с таким вопросом

есть pizza.txt .TXT:

```
ind: sushi
name: alice
item: 256899
=============
ind: pizza
name: sumit
item: 764061
=============
ind: sushi
name: alice
item: 256899
=============
ind: sushi
name: john
item: 674788
=============
ind: sushi
name: alex
item: 757864
```

мне надо что бы код вырезал слова опираясь на то есть ли в текстовике слово pizza и вырезать слова под словом pizza

мой код на python:

```
with open(os.path.join('pizza.txt'), mode='r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as filee
                for line in filee:
                        for line in 'pizza':
                            filee.readlines()
                            name = line.strip('name: ')
                            item = line.strip('item: ')
                            print(name)
                            print(item)
```

на выводе хочу что бы получилось так:

```
print(name)
print(item)
>>sumit
>>764061
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями. Ищем последовательность строк с помощью `re.findall` по шаблону, по нему вычленяем текст для строк `name` и `item` в список кортежей.

```
import re

with open('pizza.txt', mode='r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
    data = file.read()
    finds = re.findall('ind: pizza\nname: (\w+)\nitem: (\d+)', data)
```

Дальше можно любым способом распечатать:

```
for f in finds:
    print(*f, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Кажется вам нужно что-то такое?

```
with open(os.path.join('pizza.txt'), mode='r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as filee:
  lines =[s.strip() for s in filee.readlines()]
  for i in range(0,len(lines),2):
    if lines[i] == 'ind: pizza':
      name = lines[i+1].strip('name: ')
      item = lines[i+2].strip('item: ')
      print(name)
      print(item)
```

Вывод:

```
sumit
764061
```

Comment: у меня не работает, ничего не выводит